# Unable to Query list's items using Rest API + CAML. Error "One or more field types are not installed properly...."

Tags: caml-query, sharepoint-rest-api, caml, ajax

I want to query my custom list using REST API + CAML. And I have to use POST request to be able to get the managed metadata values (mainly Label), so I tried the below Ajax request:

```
var body = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
           'ViewXml': "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Id'/><Value Type='Number'>"+orderID+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
        } 
   };   
    $.ajax({
     url: "/*****/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('*****')/GetItems",
     method: "POST",   
     contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",     
     async: false,
     data: JSON.stringify(body),
     headers: { 
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()       
     },
     success: function (data) {
         if(data.d.results.length>0){

            var items=data.d.results;

            for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
               //code goes here

            }
            console.log(data);

         }

      }  
    });
```

but I got the following exception:

> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list
>   settings page to delete these fields.

So can anyone advice on the above error? Although the list have a field named Id of type Number.

Comment: Use ID instead of Id and check

Comment: @GautamSheth i got lost on this as inside the REST API result the ID will be as follow `<d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">417</d:Id>` so ithought i need to use Id!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAML query requires InternalName of the field. So `Id` is reserved for item's ID

If you want to get an item by id then `url: "/*****/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('*****')/items("+orderID+")"`

And rename your field.